# Matlab error: constructor must preserve the class

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, constructor

connected question: [Returning an object of a second class through the constructor of first class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473489/returning-an-object-of-a-second-class-through-the-constructor-of-first-class) but the answer doesn't seem to be of much help for me.

I'm having trouble with Matlab constructors. I want to create a class A and a subclass B, such that I can provide the constructor of B with either the arguments needed for A, or with an object of A itself. Looks like this

```
classdef A

    properties
        arg;
    end

methods

    function self = A(arg)
        if isa(arg, 'A')
            self = arg;
        else
            self.arg = arg^2;
        end
    end

end
end

classdef B < A

methods

    function self = B(arg)
        self = self@A(arg);
    end

end
end
```

Now, calling A(4) gives

```
A(4)
ans = 
A with properties:
arg: 16
```

and calling A(A(4)) gives

```
A(A(4))
ans = 
A with properties:
arg: 16
```

as expected. Calling B(4) gives

```
B(4)
ans = 
B with properties:
arg: 16
```

which is fine as well, and finally

```
B(A(4))
When constructing an instance of class 'B', the constructor must preserve the class of the returned object.
Error in B (line 6)
        self = self@A(arg);
```

leads to the title error. Doesn't self@A(arg) call the constructor of A with the argument arg, which will then return an instance of A in any case? I don't see the difference.

In fact, this would mean that I can not create an instance of B from an instance of A, since I must know the exact arguments, which had been used to create A. Otherwise I can't call the super constructor, obviously.
(In other languages one would simply overload the constructor, but this cant be done in matlab)

Can someone please explain what I am missing here?

Many thanks

Kenji

Comment: *since I must know the exact arguments, which had been used to create A* - You could store those arguments in a property of A and access them in B's constructor, if it is passed an A object.

Comment: Thanks, that would surely be a way to do it, however it doesn't really look smooth. I would have to add an if Statement in every subclass, which is actually precisely what I tried to avoid.
Can you explain why my original Approach doesn't work?
Btw, I just realized that B(B(4)) does work.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say why your original approach doesn't work except that it looks like another case where MATLAB says "I know what you're trying to do but I'm not going to let you do it" ;-(